# Is it possible to initialize an object in a class function, not in constructor

Tags: c++, object, constructor, member-initialization

Hey i am looking to see if there is a way for me to initialize a member object in a class function. Meaning i would like not to use the member initializer list.

I don't want:`Foo::Foo(): bar(), barBar(){}`

but want: `Foo::setup(){bar(); barBar() }`

Hope you can help me out here.

Comment: What is the reason for this?  Do you need some code to run to determine what the members should be set to?

Comment: The class function could be implemented to construct and return a new object, like a factory.

Comment: I need to load some files before i can create my objects because the require the files as parameters.

Comment: Then use a factory or create a method initialize for your object and call this method once you have loaded your files to initialize your object.

Comment: Can you guide me in the direction of where i can learn more about factories. I have not worked with that yet.

Comment: `C++ factory method pattern` via google-fu will bring back *hundreds* of topics on the subject.